# Google Sheets Auto Repeat Formula

Tags: google-sheets

This formula works if I manually paste it into each row; however, I need to know how to get the formula to auto populate into new rows as the are added.

`=ARRAYFORMULA(countif(A:A&B:B&E:E,A2&B2&"Finished"))`

Answer (score 1):

Your formula gives the number of accurancies:

- A + B + E = A2 + B2 + "Finished"

So we have only one possible output. To make it show each time, when the corresponding row matches, use this formula, paste in a second row:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(A2:A&B2:B&E2:E=A2:A&B2:B&"Finished",countif(A:A&B:B&E:E,A2&B2&"Finished"),))
```

or this one:

```
=ArrayFormula(--(A2:A&B2:B&E2:E=transpose(A2&B2&"Finished"))*countif(A:A&B:B&E:E,A2&B2&"Finished"))
```

To help you more, need example file with desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISTEXT(A2:A),countif(A2:A&B2:B&E2:E,A2:A&B2:B&"Finished"),))
```